# Test publish permissions for Facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to test the publish permissions for my facebook app, however when using the graph api(s) to either like or comment, I get an error from the facebook server.

The code being used to post a like is as below:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("url", "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2015381/");
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/" + facebookObjectId + "/likes",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "FACEBOOK GRAPH RESPONSE FOR POSTING LIKE: " + response);
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
```

The corresponding error that is being generated is:

```
FACEBOOK GRAPH RESPONSE FOR POSTING LIKE: {Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) App does not have permission to make this call}}
```

essentially suggesting that ***App does not have permission to make this call***

Comment: why not just use the like button plugin with the url? i don´t think you can like external links with the api, and there is no serious application for this anyway.

Comment: I want to use the feature on a custom button and not their standard button.

Comment: that would be a bad idea, those are facebook likes and people would expect a facebook like button. either way, it is not possible anyway afaik. you can try with the publish_actions permission though.

Answer (score 0):

**To post custom like:**

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("object", linkURL);
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/" + Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId() + "/og.likes",
            params,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "FACEBOOK GRAPH RESPONSE FOR POSTING LIKE: " + response);
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

**To delete custom like:**

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("object", linkURL);
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/" + likeActionInstanceId,
            params,
            HttpMethod.DELETE,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "FACEBOOK GRAPH RESPONSE FOR DELETING LIKE: " + response);
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

Here the `likeActionInstanceId` is the `id` received after submitting the like successfully.

**NOTE**: Comments can't be added as of now from your own app. Comment Mirroring is in beta phase at Facebook.